# Excel VBA - multiple value changes causes multiple saves to log sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with four sheets:

1. Magazyn
2. Log
3. WZD
4. PZD

Workbook functionalities:

- If anything changes in columns B:I in sheet 'Magazyn", then the row
  is saving in sheet 'Log'.
- If value in column F in sheet 'Magazyn' changes to 'Biuro' then  the row is saving in sheet 'PZD'.
- If value in column F in sheet 'Magazyn' changes to anything else than 'Biuro' then  the row is saving in sheet 'PZD'.
- `Sub Confirmation` is checking if  values in columns: B and I in sheet 'Magazyn' are duplicated, if yes message box is appearing.
- It works fine if I'm changing value in a single cell. If I'm pasting one or more new row/rows in sheet 'Magazyn', I'm receving `Run-time error "13": Type mismatch`

What I try to get:

1. Changing one or more cells in sheet 'Magazyn' in range B:I will make input in sheet 'Log'
2. `Sub Confirmation` will work with more than one value.

Could you assist with it?

All code below:

```
   Private myTarget As Range
    
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
        Set myTarget = Target
        CopyPaste
        CopyPasteWZD
        CopyPastePZD
        
        Confirmation Target
        
    End Sub
    
    Sub CopyPaste()
    
        If Not Intersect(myTarget, Range("B:I")) Is Nothing Then
    
            LastRow = Sheets("Logi").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    
            Sheets("Magazyn").Range("A" & myTarget.Row & ":J" & myTarget.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Logi").Range("A" & LastRow)
    
        End If
    
    End Sub
    
    Sub CopyPastePZD()
    
        If Not Intersect(myTarget, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
    
            LastRow = Sheets("PZD").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    
            If myTarget.Value = "Biuro" Then
    
                Sheets("Magazyn").Range("A" & myTarget.Row & ":J" & myTarget.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PZD").Range("A" & LastRow)
            End If
    
        End If
    
    End Sub
    
    Sub CopyPasteWZD()
    
    
        If Not Intersect(myTarget, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
    
            LastRow = Sheets("WZD").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    
            If myTarget.Value <> "Biuro" Then
    
                Sheets("Magazyn").Range("A" & myTarget.Row & ":J" & myTarget.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("WZD").Range("A" & LastRow)
            End If
    
        End If
    End Sub
    
    Sub Confirmation(ByVal Target As Range)
        With Target
            If (.Column <> 2 And .Column <> 9) Or .Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(.Column), .Value) > 1 Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .ClearContents
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                MsgBox "Wprowadzona wartosc juz istnieje"
            End If
    
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to loop through every cell in `Target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each cell of the changed range i.e. `Target`. Also, there isn't a need to create another variable `myTarget` since it is the same as `Target`. It's just extra steps FYI.

1. Create a range loop for the changed cells
2. Pass the incremental variable to each sub with each sub updated to take a parameter rather a global variable

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
Dim xTarget As Range

For Each xTarget In Target
    CopyPaste xTarget
    CopyPasteWZD xTarget
    CopyPastePZD xTarget
    Confirmation xTarget
Next xTarget
        
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CopyPastePZD(xTarget As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(xTarget, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
    
        LastRow = Sheets("PZD").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    
        If myTarget.Value = "Biuro" Then
            Sheets("Magazyn").Range("A" & xTarget.Row & ":J" & xTarget.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PZD").Range("A" & LastRow)
        End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

*Note here is example of one following sub updated. For each sub you need to update the range variable and incorporate the range parameter. This removes the need for your variable `myTarget`*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed code, deleted myTarget. And also changed all `myTarget` variables to `xTarget`  But now, when I'm trying to change anything in 'Magazyn' I'm receiving error message: `Run-time error '424' Object Required`.

Comment: Any specific line?

Comment: After click Debug I get `CopyPaste (xTarget)` marked yellow

Comment: Did you update the parameter for the sub `CopyPaste`? It should be `Sub CopyPaste(xTarget as Range)`

Comment: Yes. All subs now are like: `SubName(xTarget As Range)`. And sub `Worksheet_Change` is change to your version

Comment: remove the parenthesis

Comment: It was my mistake :) I still had myTarget variable in one place. Could you help me with one more thing? Now if I paste data in new row in sheet 'Magazyn' it is multiplied in 'Log' sheet. It look like every run of loop in 'for each' creates a new row in 'Log' sheet. Do you know how can I insert only one row in 'Log' sheet.